# Какой код выполняется в GetHashCode для созданного мной класса?

Tags: c#, hashcode

Пришлите, пожалуйста, ссылку на исходный код .net framework, где работает GetHashCode для объявленного мной класса.

Поиск по исходникам на [referencesource.microsoft.com](https://referencesource.microsoft.com) не приносит ровным счетом ничего по задаче, поскольку у System.Object [GetHashCode](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/runtimehelpers.cs,154) объявлен с extern и не имеет реализации:

```
[MethodImplAttribute(MethodImplOptions.InternalCall)]
public static extern int GetHashCode(Object o);
```

Где находится реализация такого метода?

Comment: Данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что тут не сервис по поиску исходников, рефлектор или [https://referencesource.microsoft.com](https://referencesource.microsoft.com) вам в помощь.

Comment: Я понимаю, что вопрос такого рода, но поиск по исходникам не приносит ровным счетом ничего по задаче, поскольку у System.Object GetHashCode - extern.

Comment: а зачем вам это вообще знать? Если вам не нравится механизм по умолчанию, переопределите его.

Comment: Как раз таки потому, что я и хочу переопределить его, сделать свой алгоритм. Допустим, чтобы объекты с равными полями имели равные хеши.

Comment: вам для этого не надо знать алгоритм по умолчанию, просто [переопределите метод](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/reference/generate-equals-gethashcode-methods?view=vs-2019) и все дела.

Comment: Если точнее, я делаю уникальный идентификатор для .NET-объекта, зависящий от полей. А для этого надо знать, как реализована система хеширования.

Comment: приедите код вашего класса. Вам не  надо знать, как работает готовая система хеширования, чтобы написать свой метод. Более того, с большой вероятностью, вам не получится создать уникальный идентификатор - хеш - это не идентификатор, он не уникальный для большинства объектов. Разные объкты с одинаковым хешем называются коллизия.

Comment: Раньше мой проект (хранение объектов любых типов в словаре по указателю) работал исключительно на GetHashCode (год без каких либо проблем), я теперь узнал про возможное переопределение пользователем хеша и понял, что надо исключить его вероятность.

Comment: Словарь (если вы про `Dictionary<>`) работает не только с GetHashCode, но и с Equals и прекрасно справляется с коллизиями. Но и вы начали с того, что вам надо знать имплементацию GetHashCode, продолжили тем, что вам надо переопределить GetHashCode, а сейчас вам надо исключить вероятность переопределения. Это три разных вопроса. Думаю, вам надо подумать, определиться что вам действительно нужно, и переформулировать вопрос.

Comment: Да, я действительно задал 3 вопроса. Значит, так: мне надо знать имплементацию GetHashCode, чтобы реализовать его функционал и игнорировать переопределение в классах.

Comment: с имплементацией точно не помогу, имхо это просто потеря времени её искать, это просто тупо ничего не даст. Раз у вас 3 вопроса, то задавайте их отдельно.

Comment: Переопределение мне вовсе не нужно, я беру объекты неизвестных на этапе компиляции классов и кладу в Dictionary<int, object>. Либо я обращаюсь к объекту, обнаружив его по указателю, либо мне надо по объекту найти сам указатель. С последней задачей GetHashCode помогал прекрасно справляться.

Comment: я не понял, что вы имеете ввиду под указателем, и словарь подразумевает отсутствие дублей в ключах, что неверно для хешей, который могут дублироваться

Comment: А при каких условиях хеши могут дублироваться?

Comment: Сами подумайте, вот хеш объекта в дотнете это что? Это число int, так? Это сколько возможных хешей? Миллиарда 2-4? А теперь представьте строку. Сколько возможных строк в природе? Бесконечное количество. То есть хочешь не хочешь, но разные строки могут иметь одинаковый хеш. Как и любой класс с двумя int полями. Просто потому что комбинаций двух целых полей тоже больше 4 миллиардов.

Comment: @tym32167 Зачем же закрывать? Как реализован определенный метод - вполне нормальный вопрос. Автор же заранее не может знать, что ищет не в том направлении.

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight ну закрыли бы вопрос, автор бы его переформулировал, открыли бы его заново, не вижу тут проблем.

Answer (score 0):

Для запрета переопределения функции есть ключевое слово `sealed`, пример

```
public class MyClass
{
    public sealed override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return base.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

В таком случае наследники не смогут его переопределить

```
public class MyClassExt : MyClass
{
    public override int GetHashCode() // ошибка!
    {
        return base.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

Comment: Вопрос был не про это.

Comment: `Раньше мой проект (хранение объектов любых типов в словаре по указателю) работал исключительно на GetHashCode (год без каких либо проблем), я теперь узнал про возможное переопределение пользователем хеша и понял, что надо исключить его вероятность` - коммент автора вопроса.

Comment: Хотя если вы знаете, про что именно вопрос, то поделитесь инфой, я после общения с автором в комментах так и не понял этого :)

Comment: "Где находится реализация такого метода?" - из вопроса. (как я понял подразумевается реализация метода GetHashCode по умолчанию). Хотя судя по комментам - кто его знает, что конкретно он хотел.

Comment: вот и я про то же, у автора скорее всего XY проблема, я пробовал понять его изначальную проблему, когда он дошел до переопределения `GetHashCode`, я ему накатал ответ, но и после этого мы продолжили выяснения в комментах. Ответ я на всякий случай решил оставить, может ему или кому другому будет полезно.

Answer (score 0):

Стандартная реализация GetHashCode для object возвращает значение, генерируемое отдельно для каждого объекта, и никак не зависит от значений его полей (т.е., его использование при сравнении эквивалентно сравнению по ссылке). Так как он реализован в CLR, исходников GetHashCode из .NET Framework нет в официальных источниках. Реализацию GetHashCode из .NET Core можно посмотреть в исходниках CoreCLR (C++). Для этого нужно сначала найти соответствующий неуправляемый метод в файле [coreclr/src/vm/ecalllist.h](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/dfa5d039140035636e2c88aa7934f80d9c9d2aa6/src/coreclr/src/vm/ecalllist.h). Для RuntimeHelpers.GetHashCode это 
[ObjectNative::GetHashCode](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/d215959b706aab254b979eb70cb48c245582f14a/src/coreclr/src/classlibnative/bcltype/objectnative.cpp#L87):

```cpp
FCFuncElement("GetHashCode", ObjectNative::GetHashCode)
```

Если дойти до получения самого значения, то это будет метод [Thread.GetNewHashCode](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/d215959b706aab254b979eb70cb48c245582f14a/src/coreclr/src/vm/threads.h#L1738):

```cpp
inline DWORD GetNewHashCode()
{
    LIMITED_METHOD_CONTRACT;
    // Every thread has its own generator for hash codes so that we won't get into a situation
    // where two threads consistently give out the same hash codes.
    // Choice of multiplier guarantees period of 2**32 - see Knuth Vol 2 p16 (3.2.1.2 Theorem A).
    DWORD multiplier = GetThreadId()*4 + 5;
    m_dwHashCodeSeed = m_dwHashCodeSeed*multiplier + 1;
    return m_dwHashCodeSeed;
}
```

То же самое в [исходниках .NET Framework CLR](https://web.archive.org/web/20100826092233/http://www.koders.com/cpp/fidA059682663204D622AA0406F037499FCE5B1BEE9.aspx), из неофициальных источников.

---

Таким образом, если нужен пример вычисления хэш-кода для своего типа, исходный код object.GetHashCode бесполезен. В качестве примера реализации вычисления хэш-кода на основе полей объекта вместо него можно взять например [код генератора метода GetHashCode для анонимных типов](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/blob/91571a3bb038e05e7bf2ab87510273a1017faed0/src/Compilers/CSharp/Portable/Compiler/AnonymousTypeMethodBodySynthesizer.cs#L162) из исходников компилятора C#.

Comment: `возвращает значение, уникальное для каждого экземпляра объекта` я же в комментариях пояснял, что оно не уникальное. Это не идентификатор. Есть же конкретные требования к хеш функции и уникальности в этих требованиях нет.